# clearInterval not working with handle

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, clearinterval

I have a problem with clearInterval function. In Typescript it is highlighted red "argument types do not match parameters". So I am unable to log out user.
Here is the function:

```
private check() {
    if (this.isLogged) {
        var timer = setInterval(() => {
            if(this.Expiration < new Date()) {
                this.signOut.emit(true);
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Can I do this instead of clearInterval ?

```
timer = null;
```

Comment: Are you *quite sure* it's the `clearInterval` call that has the error you quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I do this instead of clearInterval ?

No. Doing that would have no effect on the interval timer. It just sets the `timer` variable to `null`.

> In Typescript it is highlighted red "argument types do not match parameters".

Make it match. One would have expected [type inference](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) to be correctly assigning `timer` the type `number`, but the error you've quoted suggests that's not happening. You can do it explicitly:

```
var timer : number = setInterval(() => {
// -------^^^^^^^^
```